# In Adobe Acrobat, how can I pick my Custom Color with merely 1 click?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Please see the GIF below. My Custom Green Color (R, G, B) = (76, 230, 0) isn't appearing when I click the Color icon; only the Default Colors appear.

It's too unproductive to click (1) on the Color icon, (2) 'Other Colors', (3) then my Custom Green Color every time I fancy it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, as far as I know, to modify the user interface of Adobe Acrobat Pro.

The only solution that I see is to create a shortcut to a macro that will do the
required 8 clicks for you. This assumes that the Adobe window is always
displayed at the same position on the screen, so that the clicks are always
on the same well-defined spots.

Required tools that need to be installed:

- [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) - a macro processor (and more)
- [Pulover’s Macro Creator](https://www.macrocreator.com/download/) - a macro recorder

The procedure is divided into two parts.

**Part 1 : Record the clicks**

- Run Pulover’s Macro Creator
- Set the menu *Macro > Recording Options* as below, to record only clicks
  (Keystrokes are incidental):

  [image]
- Start recording using menu *Macro > Record Macro*
- Ensure that Acrobat is the front windows
- Click <kbd>F9</kbd> to start recording
- Click in Acrobat on the *Color* button, then on "Other Color...", your
  custom color and finally on OK
- Click <kbd>F9</kbd> again to stop recording
- Click in the traybar on the icon of Pulover’s Macro Creator to open its window
- You will see the AutoHotkey commands in the right-hand pane, so click in it
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text to the clipboard

**Part 2 : Create the macro**

- Use Notepad or another editor to create a text file named `something.ahk`
- Add a first line for the shortcut key, paste the above text after it,
  and terminate with a `return` command. My macro looked like this, where I used
  <kbd>F12</kbd> as the shortcut key:

  ```
  F12::
  Click, 1353, 414 Left, , Down
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 1352, 415 Left, , Up
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 1403, 587 Left, , Down
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 105, 146 Left, , Up
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 37, 382 Left, , Down
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 37, 382 Left, , Up
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 98, 476 Left, , Down
  Sleep, 10
  Click, 98, 476 Left, , Up
  return
  ```
- Double-click the `.ahk` file to start it executing. It will create a green "H"
  icon in the traybar that you can right-click and select `Exit` to stop.
  If you always want this script to execute, copy it to the user Startup folder at
  `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.
- While this script is running, pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> will do the 8 required
  clicks automatically.

For more information see this AutoHotkey documentation :

- [List of Keys, Mouse Buttons, and Joystick Controls](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [Click command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm)
- [Sleep command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Busy week! Let me try and get back to you.